# Why does :t foldMap id yield t m -> m, and not t a -> m

Tags: haskell

`foldMap` has the following type:

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

If you partially apply `id` to foldMap you get

```
foldMap id :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => t m -> m
```

Why does the `t a` change to a `t m` when applying `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`id` is of type `x -> x` which means when `foldMap` takes it as an argument, `a` becomes constrained to be the same type as `m`. Call this new type `n`. Because `a` is a free type variable, the only constraint we have on `n` comes from `m`, namely that `n` is a monoid.

This results in the type signature `(Foldable t, Monoid n) => t n -> n` after removing the initial `n -> n` due to application on `id`. This is the type signature you observe (after simple relabeling of `n` to be `m` again since the type variable names are arbitrary).

Answer (score 4):

`a` has no restrictions on it, but `m` must be a monoid. Since `id` must return a monoid, it must also take a monoid as an argument as well which means the Foldable must wrap a monoid.

That is, you can only `foldMap` the function `id` over a `Foldable` that consists of monoidal values.